# Error rvm CLI may not be called from within /etc/rvmrc

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, fedora

After installing a multiuser (systemwide) RVM on Fedora 17 I get the following error when logging in:

```
Error:
      /etc/rvmrc is for rvm settings only.
      rvm CLI may NOT be called from within /etc/rvmrc.
      Skipping the loading of /etc/rvmrc
```

and the following when logging out:

```
bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

My /etc/rvmrc file is

```
umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

I've searched Google and SO for answers and all that I find do not appear to be relevant to this case, they are mostly OSX.

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Comment: this looks like rvm bug and those is not a question to other users but to developers, open a ticket here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for their support, they say it's on IRC, but Github is much more reasonable.

Comment: you get this url displayed when installing and updating rvm, it is also place where code is hosted, that should not be that hard to find

Comment: Thanks, I've already filed an issue. As an ex-systems-programmer I always assume a problem is probably not with the system until proven otherwise.

Comment: Rvm is used in so many scenarios that it would be impossible to test it all with current implementation, rvm2 will be written in ruby which will allow virtualization layer and unit testing everything - which should provide more reliable code ... till then some cases like this are bugs.